# Gatsby: Accessing props array's length in a component leads to TypeError (property undefined)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components, gatsby, react-props

## Problem

In `index.js` I passed a `modifier` prop with the value of `["fullWidth", "secondMod"]` to the imported `Container` sub-component:

**index.js**

```
<Container>
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
</Container>

// Modifier Prop comes here
<Container modifier={["fullWidth", "secondMod"]}>
    <Img fluid={data.placeholderImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />
</Container>
```

Over in `container.js`, I want to access the array in the `console.log`:

**container.js**

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Styles
import container from "../styles/components/container.module.scss"

const Container = (props) => {
  console.log(props.modifier.length);   // TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  console.log(props.modifier);          // (2) ["fullWidth", "secondMod"]
  console.log(props.children.length);   // 3

  return (
    <section className={container.section}>
      <div className={`${container.container} ${props.modifier}`}>
          {props.children}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Container
```

Nonetheless, the first `console.log(props.modifier.length)` throws an error. The error's page tite is saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Same e.g. for using `props.modifier[0]`.

### Problem Source

Thanks to the comment of @PompolutZ, the problem for the error is the first `<Container>` in **index.js**. Since it does not pass a `modifier` prop, `props.modifier` and `props.modifier.length` are undefined.
[image: container.js:22 is called twice. First time called, it is undefined.]

## Solution needed

Following the **Problem Source**, I don't know what is Best Practice for differentiating between sub-components (here `<Container>`) that pass a prop and those which don't. I still want to process the props, but don't want React to throw an error, if there is one that didn't pass a prop.

Comment: As you have correctly assesed, you have two instances of that Container component, fist one without modifier prop and second one with modifier prop. Thats why you get an error accessing length of modifier for the first instance, and everything is fine for the second instance.

Comment: Ah got it. Does it mean I have to run *if-else* to check if a `modifier` prop was passed to ensure that those `<Container>`s that don't pass anything won't throw an error? Or what is **best practice** here?

Answer (score 0):

Using `defaultProps` can prevent React from throwing an Error. In this case that would mean to add the following code to **container.js** after the closing bracket (`}`) of `const Container` and before `export default Container`:

```
Container.defaultProps = {
  modifier: [],
}
```

Also see the React Documentation on [default Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would have written it like this (container.js):

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Styles
import container from "../styles/components/container.module.scss"

export default ({ children, modifier = [] }) => {
  console.log(modifier && modifier.length);
  console.log(modifier && modifier);
  console.log(children && children.length);

  return (
    <section>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </section>
  );
};
```